# How to create/destroy a nested_form with the change of a f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, onchange

In my rails application i have the following code
In views/patients/_form.html.erb

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sex %><br />
    <%= f.select :sex, [['Male','Female'],['Θ','1']] %>
  </div>



  <div>
   <%= f.fields_for :female_patient do |fp| %>
    <%=render   "female_patient_fields", :f => fp %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
   <p><%=link_to_add_fields "Add Female Info", f, :female_patient %></p>
```

The code in the partial is this
In views/patients/_female_patient_fields.html.erb

```
 =====FEMALE INFO=====
      <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :childbirths %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :childbirths %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_period %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :last_period %>
  </div>

  <p>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
  </p>
    ====================================
  </div>
```

The

<%=link_to_add_fields "Add Female Info", f, :female_patient %>

and
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %> 
   are links to the application helper and they create and destroy the nested form for the additional fields.

In helpers/application_helper.rp

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end

end
```

The links work fine, the nested form is created/destroyed and the female_patient object is created (or not) properly. (The patient model has a **has_one** relationship with the female_patient).

What i can't figure out, is a way to call the actions of the helper when the f.select field for sex (in the first form) is changed. I want the nested form to appear when the selected value is Female, and disappear when the selected value is Male.

EDIT: The jquery functions used are :

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".female").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would use javascript (most likely jquery) to show/hide the fields. You could put an id on the div surrounding the female patient fields. In your javascript you'd then attach an on change even to the sex select box. And then the handler for the change event would determine whether or not to show/hide the female patient div.

```
$(function() {
  if($('#patient_sex').length) {
    $('#patient_sex').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).val() == '1') {
        $('#female_patient_fields').show(); // or w/e you want to call the div
      } else {
        $('#female_patient_fields').hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In the view:

```
<div id="female_patient_fields">
  ... your form fields for 
</div>
```

Comment: I am already using jquery (i edited my question) and it works fine when i click on the respective create/destroy link, but i am pretty bad at jquery (or javascript for that matter) and i am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I don't understand the need to have the add/remove links since female_patient info is a has_one relationship not has_many. My suggestion, the answer I gave, is what I think you really want to do, which is just to show/hide those fields.

Comment: I tried your solution and it partially works. It shows/hide the partial form correctly, but now when i create a patient that has the extra fields, the female_patient object is not created. And also the first time i go to the patient/new page the Male value is selected on the selector, and the additional fields are appearing. So i have to select Female and then again Male for them to disappear.

Comment: By creating another jquery function which is basically the same as yours but without control for the change of the selector i got rid of my second problem. But still the female_patient object does not get created.

Comment: Is there a way to call the functions in the helper from inside the jquery function??

Comment: In the new action in your controller do `@patient.female_patient.build`

Comment: I have already done this. Actually since its a has_one relationship it should be @patient.build_female_patient, i think

Comment: You're right about that, it's `build_<has_one_model_name>`. So if you have that it should work, weird.

Comment: It seems like the female_patient attributes should just be placed on the patient table, since really they are just attributes of a patient that happens to be female. Good database design should minimize one-to-one relationships like this. My answer still applies to this scenario as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the db schema is fixed and i can't change it. Is there a  way to click on the links that i already have and work from the inside the script?

Comment: In your model, you could try `accepts_nested_attributes_for :female_patient`, then your fields for would be `f.fields_for :female_patient_attributes do |fp|...`

Comment: I have already done this too.. I should have written the code for my models too.. It's my first question in stackoverflow and it shows ... :)

Comment: Ok, i made it work. But now when i create a patient that has its sex set to Male a female patient is also created with all its fields set to null. I tried adding ':reject_if => proc { |a| (a['sex'].to_i == 0 )}' to the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' line,  but it does not work (patients with the sex field set to "female" are also rejected).

Comment: I still think (database design wise) it'd be better to keep the female patient fields on the patient model. The reject if portion is using the attributes of the female_patient model. So you'd need to do something like `proc { |a| a[:childbirths].blank? && a[:last_period].blank? }` If these attributes were on the patient model you could just do some conditional validations (if needed). Like `validates :childbirths, :presence => true :if => lambda { sex == '1' }`.

Comment: Sadly i cannot change the db design... And i can't reject on the condition that all the fields in the female_patient are blank.

Comment: The only other thing I would suggest is to ditch the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and just create the two models in the controller (or make a method on the patient model to) manually. I think the scope of your new problem is outside of your initial question (showing/hiding the fields). Maybe you should post a new question with the new issue.